# Go to specific datetime in fullcalendar or any specific event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar.js for booking system in my website. I am using function

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date());
```

Problem I am facing is that it takes me to required date in the calendar, but I also want to move to specific time span in the calendar.

Can anybody please help me on this point?

Thanks
Manoj.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't find any solution for scroll dynamically to the time slot in FullCalendar, so what I did here is that on clicking the `div` I'm passing the time to the `function scrollToTime(time)`.

```
<div class="button">Scroll to time dynamically</div>
```

Passing time to the function

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function () {
    var time = '15:30:00';

    scrollToTime(time);
});
```

I've `$('.fc-axis')` as `targets` and looping through it to check whether the calendar time slot is same as the time that I passed on `div` click. If the condition is true, scroll `document body` to the top position of the item, something like this:

```
function scrollToTime(time) {
    var targets = $('.fc-axis');

    $.each(targets, function () {
        var scrollable = $(this),
            closestTime = $(this).closest('tr').data('time');

        if (closestTime === time) {
            $([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
                scrollTop: scrollable.offset().top - 100
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
};
```

Perhaps, this isn't a good approach and the logic for dynamic scroll has to be added in the plugin but for now there is no option to scroll dynamically, and the only possibility in FullCalendar is to set the initial scroll. Check [scrollTime](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/scrollTime) for more details and you can also check this [Method for scrolling to a time #467](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/467)

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
 },
 defaultDate: '2015-02-02',
 defaultView: 'month',
 slotDuration: '00:10:00',
 minTime: "8:00:00",
 maxTime: "20:00:00",
 selectable: true,
 selectHelper: true,
 dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  if (view.name == 'month') {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', start);
  }
  else {
   alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
   alert('Current view: ' + view.name);
  }
 },
 editable: true,
 eventClick: function(event, element) {
  alert(event.title + " click on " + event.start.format() + " end time " + event.end.format());
 },
 eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
   revertFunc();
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents')
  }
  alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format() + " end time " + event.end.format());
 },
 eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
   revertFunc();
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
  }
 },
 eventLimit: true,
 views: {
  agenda: {
   eventLimit: 2 // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
  }
 },
 events: [
   {
    id: 9,
    title: 'dinner',
    start: '2015-02-16T10:00:00',
    end: '2015-02-16T10:30:00'
   },
   {
    id: 9,
    title: 'lunch',
    start: '2015-02-17T10:00:00',
    end: '2015-02-17T10:30:00'
   },
   {
    id: 9,
    title: 'breakfast',
    start: '2015-02-18T10:00:00',
    end: '2015-02-18T10:30:00'
   },
   {
    id: 9,
    title: 'full event',
    start: '2015-02-17',
    end: '2015-02-17'
   }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Instead of posting a wall of code, please consider breaking it up and write some explanation of how each part solves the question.